# SQL query validation - not testing each time

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I've got a php page with javascript passing in a string of values from inputs to aa insert.php page.

On this insert.php page, I test whether or not the email that was passed in already exists in the database. My query works in this regard, but what happens is the error gets passed back to the page and outputs as a validation error.

What I want to happen would be after the validation error sends it's output. The user can then change that field and try again. For some reason, my insert.php page doesn't check again for this, and if it does, it won't let the user input a different value to continue. (the error message stays on the screen and won't allow unique inputs through)

What's wrong with my sql query/php?

```
$errors = Array();

$sql="SELECT 1 FROM data_table WHERE email = '".$email."' LIMIT 1";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$varcomp = $sth->execute();
if ($varcomp != '0') {
    $errors[] = '<span style="color:red;">Limit one entry per person.</span>';
}


if (sizeof($errors) > 0) {
    $result = array(
    "errors" => implode("<br/>", $errors),
    "success" => 0);
    die(json_encode($result));
}
```

To reiterate, the sql query works fine the first time through validating whether or not the email is already in the data table. However, after it spits that error out on the page "Limit one entry per person", even if the user changes the email to something unique, the error message doesn't go away and won't allow the new unique email to either be checked again or submitted.

Comment: Is this the complete code? You're not actually querying the database. Also, after your show the errors, you use `die()` to show the message - this kills the script

Comment: @BenPearlKahan no, there's also code where I connect to the database. The only code relevant to the db at this point is the second line of code above where I make the query to select. Also, the die prevents the code AFTER the code I wrote here to be executed. My problem is that I guess the email is only being tested once. and if it returns with the error, the error stays for all other times after even if the email gets changed to something unique

Comment: Look at your code posted. If the `$sql` string doesn't equal the `'0'` string, then you're loading the `$errors` array with the error message. With this you're gonna get the error message every time.

Comment: @JonathanM Yes, but doesn't that else if take care of it going through it a second time? meaning, the second time through (after the email is changed to something unique), runs the query and sets $sql to '0' then, goes into the else if. sets the errors array to '0' and then checks the size again..

Comment: @JonathanM I mean apparently I am doing something wrong here, but how can I fix my code so that the second time through after changing the email to something unique, it checks it again and deletes that error message if it is unique?

Comment: You need to parameterize your queries before bobby tables makes an appearance. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SeanLange can you please advise, or post an answer that would give me the best possible way to check if the email being passed in is already in the table - and if it's already there, then going back and inputting a unique email afterwards, wouldn't give errors?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever execute the SQL statement in the database. You are just comparing the string `SELECT 1 FROM data_table WHERE email =whatever@email.com LIMIT 1` to `0`, which will ALWAYS return false. Instead you should execute the SQL, catch the results (and error) and then make your decisions based on that. Like... your SQL is fine, you just don't actually do anything with it.

Comment: @JNevill I just changed the code, is what I placed there correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query code like this:

```
$sql="SELECT email FROM data_table WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($email));
if ($sth->rowCount() != 0) {
    $errors[] = '<span style="color:red;">Limit one entry per person.</span>';
}
```

---

Using named placeholders:

```
$sql="SELECT email FROM data_table WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1"; 
$sth = $db->prepare($sql); 
$sth->execute(array(':email'=>$email));
```

- You need to count the rows, not just check if the query is successful
- Use prepared statement

Comment: This is better. `Select 1` will work fine, it just needs to select anything, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JNevill yeah you right, usually one wants to do something more useful

Comment: @meda also, I'm assuming the "?" in the first time should be the variable?

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda yes it will bind to it, use `$sth->execute(array($email));` , this is to prevent sql injection and escape characters as well

Comment: @meda do I need to initialize the array $email? in the code prior, I already pull an $email variable, would making it array($emaillist) matter?

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda yeah `execute()` takes an array, because it could be more then one param then it would be `$sth->execute(array($email, $password));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101797/discussion-between-noreceipt4panda-and-meda).

Comment: @meda so this is just filling up $sth, with an array, also, shouldn't "WHERE email = ?" be "WHERE email='".$email."' "?